# Terraform AWS-EKS not encrypting EBS volumes despite providing CMK or custom role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I am using [terraform AWS EKS module](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks) to create a kubernetes cluster and struggle with getting encryption to work. Due to corporate policy I have to either use the AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling_CORPORATESUFFIX role to use the default key provided by my organization  or create custom key which default AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling role can access and then use it in the terraform files as root encryption key. Neither seems to work - I've tried setting the custom role like this (tried versions with ID's / ARNs instead of role name too):

```
module "cluster" {
  version                       = "v16.2.0"
  source                        = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  cluster_name                  = var.cluster_name
  cluster_version               = var.cluster_version
  subnets                       = ["subnet1","subnet2"]
  vpc_id                        = data.aws_vpc.selected.id
  node_groups                   = var.node_groups
  cluster_delete_timeout        = "30m"
  cluster_create_timeout        = "30m"
  manage_aws_auth               = "true"
  write_kubeconfig              = "true"
  config_output_path            = "./"
  enable_irsa                   = true
  map_roles                     = local.map_roles
  map_users                     = var.map_users
  cluster_log_retention_in_days = var.cluster_log_retention
  cluster_enabled_log_types     = local.cluster_log_type
  tags                          = local.tags
  workers_group_defaults        = {
      instance_type     = "t2.small"
      iam_instance_profile_name = "AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling_CORPORATESUFFIX"
  }       
}
```

Or even setting just the custom KMS key by setting workers_group_defaults like this:

```
workers_group_defaults  = {
      instance_type     = "t2.small"
      root_kms_key_id   = "my-custom-key-id"
      root_encrypted    = true
  }
```

but with no luck at all - I can't make the AWS EKS module use my _CORPORATESUFFIX role (nodegroup creation fails because default role AWSServiceRoleForAutoScaling does not have access to default, corporate key) and when I directly provide the custom KMS key which default role can access - it seems to be entirely ignored by Terraform, default key is still used and when I check EC2 -> Launch Templates all storage volumes are listed as "default encryption", fields `root_kms_key_id = "my-custom-key-id"` and `root_encrypted = true` seem to be ignored.

Can you please advise me how to correctly use the terraform AWS EKS module to make it work / is it a known issue and it simply can't be done this way? I've seen some [issues on GitHub referencing similar problems](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/406) but in the end I didn't get any definitive answer from them.

Comment: Have you tried to use the https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/tree/master/examples/launch_templates_with_managed_node_groups maybe the file disk_encryption.tf will apply the right policy .
But to be honest I'm trying to do the same!

Comment: Looks like the updated link that @JohnBegood was referencing is this: https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/tree/master/examples/eks_managed_node_group